# How to enabled / disabled selectbox based on textbox value in dynamic way

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

How to enabled / disabled selectbox based on textbox value in dynamic way, when user entered correct in inputbox then in selectbox should enabled in dynamic way.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Select</th>
         <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" id="date1" class="form-control" name="pettycash_dt[]" required    placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"/></td>
         <td>
            <select id="category1" class="form-control exp_id" disabled name="exp_id[]" >
               <option value="" selected disabled >Select one</option>
               <option value="10">abc</option>
               <option value="11">xyz</option>
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" id="date2" class="form-control" name="pettycash_dt[]" required    placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"/></td>
         <td>
            <select id="category2" class="form-control exp_id" disabled name="exp_id[]" >
               <option value="" selected disabled >Select one</option>
               <option value="10">abc</option>
               <option value="11">xyz</option>
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" id="date3" class="form-control" name="pettycash_dt[]" required    placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"/></td>
         <td>
            <select id="category3" class="form-control exp_id" disabled name="exp_id[]" >
               <option value="" selected disabled >Select one</option>
               <option value="10">abc</option>
               <option value="11">xyz</option>
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what you tried having any demo?

Comment: what is your textbox and what is a correct value here ?

Comment: This is my [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rakeshkumar29594/ogpwf8xt/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is how i understand your question and I am not able to ask right now, so here is my answer)

I just implemented it like when the input field is the Date from Today or an day which is already in the past, its a valid Input and then the selection in the same Table row will be enabled.

i added a new class `date-picker` to the input fields for selecting all of them together and checking when a change happens:

```
 <td><input type="text" id="date2" class="form-control date-picker" name="pettycash_dt[]" required    placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"/></td>
```

in the js i check if any change happens to one of these input fields, if yes i will trigger the function and creating the todays date for checking if the input is valid. `$(this)` gives us the actuall changed element and with `.closest('tr').find('select')` we will get the selection box in our current table row. Then we just have to set `.prop('disabled', false)`
if its not valid we change it back to disabled.

```
$('.date-picker').on('change', function() {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  if ($(this).datepicker('getDate') <= currentDate) {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('select').prop('disabled', false)
  } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('select').prop('disabled', 'disabled')
  }
})
```

also i will leave you the changed fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/6uae9j5n/

Hopes that my answer helps and will clear things a little more up. :)

Comment: Thank you for your support but it is accepting invalid date also, it should not accept invalid  date ..

Comment: What is an invalid date for you?

Comment: I found an issue in my code, which was allowing the in my opinion invalid date, i updated it and cleaned the code  a little bit up. Hope now it is like you wanted.